# Can you summon a Mob Spawner of any type with commands? If so, how?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know there is some way to use monster spawners another way than to use them in their natural location...I just don't know how. Especially in normal Minecraft. There has to be some command you can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There's this really useful tool on minecraft.tools  that allows you to do this.**

Go to http://minecraft.tools/en/spawn.php, then click on the large "Create a MobSpawner" button. Fill in all the necessary inputs, and click "Generate the Command". This will generate a command that will place down a mob spawner.

Comment: I already have discovered that and I only use Minecraft tools now. :D

Answer (score 5):

The wiki has a list of NBT data for spawners here: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mob_spawner#Data_values

And a list all entity data here: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk_format#Entity_format

---

The [/setblock](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#setblock) command can create a physical block in the world, adding necessary data to tile entities:

```
/setblock X Y Z <block ID> [Damage] [replacement method] {dataTags}
```

An example, where a creeper will spawn with a fuse timer of 1 tick. Any data not specified for the spawner will use the defaults.

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:mob_spawner 0 replace {EntityId:"Creeper",SpawnData:{Fuse:1s}}
```

---

The [/give](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#give) command can create a mob spawner for inventories. The `BlockEntityTag` tag for the item format will hold potential tile data for the block when it is placed.

```
/give <player> <item ID> [Count] [Damage] {dataTags}

/give @p minecraft:mob_spawner 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{EntityId:"Creeper",SpawnData:{Fuse:1s}}}
```

Comment: what about special spawners like killer rabbit, giant, elder guardian,or  ender dragon spawners?

Comment: @JoshRimell Entity's NBT data goes inside `SpawnData`. See the Chunk Format page I linked for all NBT data for entities. Replace the `EntityId` tag with the entity ID desired (which is also included on the linked page).